# Configure Apache reverse proxy to a AWS ALB on port 443

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-elb

I've setup a Apache reverse proxy(which receives traffic from outside world via a firewall) with the below configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName xyz.example.com
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /  https://internal-voyager-dev-1960104633.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/
ProxyPassReverse /  https://internal-voyager-dev-1960104633.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLEngine on
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLProtocol All -SSLv3 -SSLv2 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
.
.
>
```

This reverse proxy is pointing to a AWS ALB on listener port 443. So the ALB then processes the request based on the rule where HOST(xyz.example.com) is mapped to a target group. But This is not working, I am getting a `502 bad gateway error`.

.

If I make config changes like pointing reverse proxy to a http://alb-cname and use the listener port 80 of AWS ALB then I am able to bring up the application but as we use a rails application we get the error saying `HTTP Origin header didn't match request.base_url`

Appreciate any ideas as to how I can solve this issue.

Comment: Does connecting to the load balancer directly work?

Comment: Yes, if I make the AWS ALB public facing it works but we need a reverse proxy in our case.